# Why doesn't onActivityResult() work?

Tags: java, android, onactivityresult

What I am aiming to do here is to change the picture of "ibChamp" from the default one to "ahri". Note that the names inside the ***s are the names of the activity.

```
***CreateBuilds.java***
 ibChamp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent champs = new Intent(CreateBuilds.this, Champions.class);
            //creates the Intent champs for startActivityForResult()
            startActivityForResult(champs, 0);
            //opens up Champions.class layout

        }
    });

 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, int data){
        //starts when this.finish() from Champions is ran
        ImageButton ibChamp = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibChamp);
        //creates the ImageButton ibChamp
        ibChamp.setImageResource(R.drawable.ahri);
        //sets the picture of ibChamp to "ahri"
};

***Champions.java****
private myapplicationtest mytestInst = new myapplicationtest();
    public void changePicture(final int champion){

    mytestInst.setInt(champion);
    //runs "setInt" from the myapplicationtest class
    this.finish();
    //closes this current layout to run onActivityResult
 }
```

In this code, the onActivityResult() does not seem to run, since after "Champions.java" is finished, "ibChamp"'s picture did not change. If there is something extremely obvious, please state it, and any questions are welcomed.

Comment: you are trying strange things :) Besides, finish() is an asynchronous call. You call **finish()** and at some point in the future, Android will finish your **activity**. You will get calls to onPause -> onStop -> onDestroy.

Comment: @rupps Oh I see, I guess I was a bit mistaken.

Comment: @rupps Is there any way to select the objects (such as buttons) on the current layout instead of specifying names?

Comment: what do you mean by "select" and "names"?

Comment: @rupps By selecting I mean to edit the buttons, instead of giving specific names such as Imagebuttontest.

Comment: @rupps For example, if I wanted to edit the image button, I would need to do imagebuttontest.editsomething. But is there a way so that I can not specify names and do something like editsomething.ImageButton[relative coordinates] or something like that?

Comment: The "objects" are all children Views of a ViewGroup. The "names" are their ID. A ViewGroup is a View that can hold children. ViewGroups are the Layouts: LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc. You can get a reference to any View by its "id" using <Activity>.findViewById or <Layout>.findViewById for the View children. You can also access by number, ie. <Layout>.getChildAt(0) will get the first children View of a given layout, and by a special object called "TAG", using <Layout>.getViewWithTag(tag). You can assign any tag to a View (ie.  "My super cool button", then access <Layout>.getViewByTag(...).

Comment: @rupps I understand the findViewById() method, but what I'm asking is that is there a way to not use ids, but use general coords of the button. There is a reason behind all this confusion, but the reason is even more confusing, but I can try to explain it if you are curious.

Comment: nope.. you'd have to do a loop 0...n and use getChildAt, then check if the coordinates are inside the view's rectangle. That wont be very difficult, if you define a Rect(angle) for each view, theres a method "contains" that tells you if a point is inside it.

Comment: @rupps I've looked into the code a bit more, and I've edited the post quite a bit. Could you take a look at it? :)

Comment: What you have now looks reasonable. What does the `Champions` activity do? What is its `onCreate()` method?

Comment: @Code-Guru Champions opens up a layout that shows some buttons, and onCreate() is the method that is called when the activity started.

Comment: What are your two activity names then?

Comment: @Code-Guru The two activity names is Champions and CreateBuilds, which are the names shown by the ***s

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to call setResult() in the activity you are finishing

Comment: @ZackFoster Could you give an example how setResult() would be used?

Comment: @ZackFoster Actually, I don't even use the requestCode in this situation, so I'm not sure if setResult() is neccesary for this, but I am not certain.

Comment: @Piofmc on the line before this.finish(), setResult(RESULT_OK);

Comment: @ZackFoster I just tried doing setResult(RESULT_OK);, but that didn't fix it sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change "int data" into "Intent data":

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, int data)
```

---->

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

Comment: This is a very good illustration of why the `@Override` annotation should be used to mark overridden methods. Had you marked this method with `@Override`, the compiler would have immediately complained that it did not actually override a base class method (due to the parameter difference) and you could have saved yourself some frustration and head-scratching. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html for more info.

Comment: @JasonC Ah, I just deleted Override for that one method accidentally, and didn't realise what it did. Well, good to know for the future :)

Answer (score 1):

`finish()` will terminate the Activity. IMHO, it does not make sense to call `finish()` and then do layout changes (I ssume on the view in the Activity to be finished).

Comment: The reason I want to finish() is so that I do the changes on the layout under this one, instead of the layout that is on top.